# Itext Error - "The method add(AreaBreak) in the type Document is not applicable for the arguments (PdfTable)"

Tags: java, itext

I have created an accessible pdf through iText. However now i trying to take input from userlike Name, Address etc in JSP and place the input somewhere in the pdf.

User gives the input in the text area (like on SO) with the ability to mark the text as Bold or Italics or create lists (I am using widgEditor for this)

I am using PdfHtml to parse the input to the pdf. As far as i know there are 2 mehtods to make this work - `convertToDocument()` method and `convertToElements()` method.

I am using `conconvertToElements()` methods since `convertToDocument()` does not give us the ablity to place parsed input to a specific position in the pdf it simply puts the input at the top of Pdf.

I have refereed to [C01E08_HelloWorld](https://git.itextsupport.com/users/bruno/repos/htmlsamples/browse/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/htmlsamples/chapter01/C01E08_HelloWorld.java) example

But while adding pdfptable to the document i am getting the following error.

Error - "The method add(AreaBreak) in the type Document is not applicable for the arguments (PdfTable)"

```
  public void createPdf(String baseUri, String src, String dest) throws IOException { 
    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
    properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);
    List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(HTML+HTML2, properties);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    for (IElement element : elements) {
        document.add(new Paragraph(element.getClass().getName()));
        document.add((IBlockElement)element);
    }


    PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(new float[] {1,1});

    document.add(t);
    document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing iText 7 with iText 5 elements. PdfPTable is an iText 5 element and can't be used with the Document class of iText 7. Please use the com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table class.

Also, check your dependencies to remove the iText 5 dependency to avoid further confusion.